# How can I filter sub-documents from MongoDB with SpringBoot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive, unwind

I have documents in a collection such as :

```
{
  "login":"xxx",
  "someAttribute":"someValue",
  "subDocs":[
    {
      "data": "val1",
      "subDocNestedArray":["WWW","AAAA"]
    },
    {
      "data": "val2",
      "subDocNestedArray":["AAAA"]
    },
    {
      "data": "val3",
      "subDocNestedArray":["ZZZ"]
    }
    ]
}
```

I retrieve all documents that match login="xxx" and subDocNestedArray="AAAA" but want only subDocs matching along other properties of the root document, ex :

```
{
  "login":"xxx",
  "someAttribute":"someValue",
  "subDocs":[
    {
      "data": "val1",
      "subDocNestedArray":["WWW","AAAA"]
    },
    {
      "data": "val2",
      "subDocNestedArray":["AAAA"]
    }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with :

```
Aggregation.unwind("$subDocs"),
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("subDocs.subDocNestedArray").is("AAAA")),
Aggregation.group("$_id")
```

that results in missing fields

```
{
  "login": null,
  "someAttribute": null,
  "subDocs":[
    {
      "data": "val1",
      "subDocNestedArray":["WWW","AAAA"]
    },
    {
      "data": "val2",
      "subDocNestedArray":["AAAA"]
    }
    ]
}
```

I did not manage to find the syntax using "redact".

Any clue ?

Make my MongoDB query return filtered results

Comment: What's the purpose of the $unwind and $group? Do you get the desired results if you only those stages completely?

Comment: Oh I see. You basically want `$filter` in spring boot

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
MatchOperation match = match(Criteria.where("login").is("xxx").and("subDocs.subDocNestedArray").is("AAAA"));
AddFieldsOperation addField = AddFieldsOperation.addField("subDocs").withValueOf(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("subDocs").as("item").by(ArrayOperators.In.arrayOf("$$item.subDocNestedArray").containsValue("AAAA")));
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, addField);
AggregationResults<XYZClass> aggResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "CollectionName",XYZClass.class);
```

In this, we have a `$match` stage to filter documents, and then an `addFields` stage, to filter the `subDocs` array. Please test it out.

Comment: Works fine, thank you.
I discovered the Filter operator but did not understand its syntax., I had no idea of  the AddFieldsOperation part

Comment: Filter creates an expression, whereas AddFields is an aggregation stage, it can add new fields to the document or update existing fields as well. @pibou